# How to make 360 degree product viewer app in android?

Tags: android, image-gallery

I would like to make an app with a 360 degree product viewer in it.But I would like user to interact with some options along it.How can I achieve it any expertise on it.Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the question? It seems like you have quite a few. What options? Do you have 3D models to render, or will you be taking photographs from all sides of an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want a 3D product viewer, you would need to get a hold of 3D models, then you would need to get to know openGL a little better.

Do you have models? If so, i'd suggest you start by getting those.

Comment: As of now I would like to make it from photographs.Which one will do the best 3d model or photograph,because I would be having all cars in it.

Comment: this is not easy, you would need to generate a 3D model out from those pictures

Comment: Any tool to generate a 3D model out from those pictures,or we have to follow the traditional xml way.Any example or tutorial on it.

Comment: there is no "traditional xml way" to generate a 3D object from a series of pictures. You need a model, not a panorama.

Comment: How to generate 3d object from a series of images,please help on this

Comment: You can browse static images, can't you?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way. Example:

http://jbk404.site50.net/360DegreeView/mobile/common.html

Just copy paste the Source code of the page and the car image sprite, then modify the variables according to your image. After that implement it in android using an Webview, taking it from the assert folder so it will be local and you will not need internet connection.